# Alternative for window function? (code example)

Tags: sql

Hope you can give me a hand. I'm looking for a different way (more "classic", maybe) to achieve the same result as this query:

```sql
WITH a AS (
SELECT dev_id,
time_stamp,
LEAD(time_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY dev_id ORDER BY time_stamp) as next_t
FROM my_table
WHERE month = 'July'
AND app_id = 1
AND event_id = 4
),
b AS (
SELECT
dev_id,
DATE_DIFF('second', time_stamp, next_t) as diff
FROM a
)
SELECT
dev_id,
AVG(diff) as AVG_pu
FROM b
GROUP BY 1
```

The final output is just an AVG function based on the past results from the subquery a and b.

I was thinking about using another subquery and an INNER JOIN ON dev_id, but I'm not sure on how to do it exactly. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the average time, then the simplest method is:

```
SELECT dev_id,
       DATE_DIFF('second', MIN(time_stamp), MAX(time_stamp)) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0) as avg_diff
FROM my_table
WHERE month = 'July' AND
      app_id = 1 AND
      event_id = 4
GROUP BY dev_id;
```

That is, the average difference is the total span divided by one less than the number of gaps.  No window functions are needed.